# Laravel shopping cart package Model Associate issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart package.

In my controller

```
Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)->associate('App\Product');
```

I've been associated `Product model`

and in view, I loop through it,

now if I die and dump it `{{ dd($item->model->id) }}`  it works but without dd `$item->model->id` doesn't work instead gives error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the line you suspect of beeing the root for you error may not be the error that is shown. If you `dd` the code after this line is no longer executed therefore a potential access" to an `id of non-object` is also not executed. Take a look further down your code to see if the problem might be in a place that is executed after your `dd` location!

Additionally you could look into the laravel `optional` helper to catch the error and return a default value: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional

Comment: Yes, this is what i told you. The line you are suspecting of beeing the error is most likely not the error line. You need to look deeper on what line causes the error!

Comment: I believe everything is fine,
but the problem is it is not working without `dd`

Comment: Yea, exactly that's what I'm asking.

Comment: I dont know your code and stated that the bug must be somewhere else. How should i answer the question with missing information. You need to find the bug by yourself if you are not providing additional information.